# Getting Id using Foreign Key in django

Tags: python, django, flask, orm, inventory

Hy Everyone...
I have five models in django..
1- Egg
2-SaleInvocie
3-SaleInvocieItem
4-PurchaseInvocie
5-PurchaseInvocieItem
My Scenario is I am making a Sale Return where I am searching for a sale invoice id and select any one id when I select the id it automatically fills the data of that invoice which includes (sale invoice and sale invocie item data). But when I save this it only saves the Sale Return data(which is actually sale invocie data that we retrieves through searching its id) it is not saving the sale return item data (which is actually sale invoice item data), because it i snot getting the id of that hidden input that stores the itme id.

and shows me this message in terminal

```
saleReturnItemName []
```

and my models are this

```
class SaleInvoice(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(),
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
searchCustomer=models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customersaleinvoice',null=True)
PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('paid', 'Paid'),
    ('unpaid', 'Unpaid'),
)
paymentType = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES,default=None)
SHIPMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'Delivery'),
    ('2', 'Pick Up'),
)
shipmentType=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIPMENT_CHOICES,default=None)
searchVehicle=models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vehiclesaleinvoice',null=True)
searchDriver=models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='driversaleinvoice',null=True)
selectNTNInInvoice=models.ForeignKey(NTN, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='selectntn',null=True)
invoiceDate=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
totalSaleAmount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
saleInvoiceAmount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
saleInvoiceDiscount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
    ('delivered', 'Delivered'),
    ('not_delivered', 'Not Delivered'),
)
shipmentStatus = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='in_progress',)


class SaleReturn(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    customerSaleReturn=models.TextField(null=True)
    paymentTypeSaleReturn = models.TextField(null=True)
    shipmentTypeSaleReturn=models.TextField(null=True)
    searchVehicleSaleReturn=models.TextField(null=True)
    searchDriverSaleReturn=models.TextField(null=True)
    selectNTNInInvoiceSaleReturn=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    invoiceDateSaleReturn=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    totalSaleAmountSaleReturn=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('not_delivered', 'Not Delivered'),
    )
    shipmentStatusSaleReturn = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='in_progress',)
    searchSaleInvoice=models.ForeignKey(SaleInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='saleinvoiceid',null=True)


class SaleInvoiceItem(models.Model):
    saleinvoice = models.ForeignKey(
        SaleInvoice,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="saleinvoiceitem"
    )
    saleInvoiceItemName=models.ForeignKey(Egg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='saleinvoiceitemegg',null=True)
    saleInvoiceItemQuantity=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleInvoiceItemUnitPrice=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleInvoiceItemTotalAmount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleInvoiceItemDiscount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleInvoiceItemDiscountPrice=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    
class SaleReturnItem(models.Model):
    salereturn = models.ForeignKey(
        SaleReturn,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="salereturnitem"
    )
    saleReturnItemName=models.ForeignKey(Egg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='salereturnitemegg',null=True)
    saleReturnItemQuantity=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleReturnItemUnitPrice=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleReturnItemTotalAmount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleReturnItemDiscount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    saleReturnItemDiscountPrice=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)

class Egg(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1
    )
    eggName = models.TextField(null=True)
    eggInSection = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='eggsection',default=1)
    eggSalePrice = models.CharField(max_length=15,default=False)
    eggPurchasePrice = models.CharField(max_length=15,default=False)
    eggStockLimit = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    eggStockQuantity = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    eggInCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='eggcategory',default=1)
    eggExpiryDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    eggGst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,default=False)
```

and this is my html fields for items

```
<tbody class="table-border-bottom-0 table-table" id="item-table-body"> 
                              
                    <tr class="item-row">                           
                        <td><h6 class="item-number"></h6></td>                           
                        <td>                                                    
                          <input type="text" for="saleReturnItemName" id="saleReturnItemName" name="saleReturnItemName" class="form-control item-name"  style="height: 40px; width: 150px;"/>                             
                          <input type="hidden" class="form-control item-id-input" id="saleReturnItemNameId" name="saleReturnItemName"  />  
                                                
                        </td>                         
                                <td>
                                    <input  type="number" class="form-control item-quantity" id="saleReturnItemQuantityId" name="saleReturnItemQuantity" style="height: 40px; width: 150px;"/>
                                </td>                 
                                <td>
                                    <input type="string" class="form-control item-price" id="saleReturnItemUnitPriceId" name="saleReturnItemUnitPrice" />
                                   
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control item-total-amount" id="saleReturnItemTotalAmountId" name="saleReturnItemTotalAmount"/>
                                   
                                </td>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control item-discount" id="saleReturnItemDiscountId" name="saleReturnItemDiscount" />
                                    
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control item-discounted-amount" id="saleReturnItemDiscountPriceId" name="saleReturnItemDiscountPrice"/>
                                    
                                </td>                                   
                    </tr>
                 
                    </tbody>
```

and my view function is this

```
def saleReturn(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('login')
elif request.user.userRole != 'admin':
    return render(request, 'pages/404.html')
else:
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            searchSaleInvoiceId = request.POST.get('searchSaleInvoice')
            searchSaleInvoice = SaleInvoice.objects.get(id=searchSaleInvoiceId)
            invoiceDateSaleReturn = request.POST.get('invoiceDateSaleReturn')

            saleReturnObject = SaleReturn(
                user=request.user,
                searchSaleInvoice=searchSaleInvoice,
                invoiceDateSaleReturn=invoiceDateSaleReturn,
            )
            saleReturnObject.invoiceDateSaleReturn = date.today()
            saleReturnObject.save()

            
            saleReturnItemName = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemName')
            print("saleReturnItemName",saleReturnItemName)
            saleReturnItemQuantity = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemQuantity')
            saleReturnItemUnitPrice = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemUnitPrice')
            saleReturnItemDiscount = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemDiscount')
            
            totalSaleAmountSaleReturn = 0.0
            saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn = 0.0
            saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn = 0.0

            for itemNameId, quantity, price, discount in zip(
                    saleReturnItemNameIds, saleReturnItemQuantities, saleReturnItemUnitPrices, saleReturnItemDiscounts
            ):
                egg_object = Egg.objects.get(id=itemNameId)

                total_amount = int(quantity) * float(price)
                if discount == '':
                    discount = 0.0
                else:
                    discount = float(discount)
                discounted_amount = total_amount - discount

                saleReturnItemObject = SaleReturnItem(
                    salereturn=saleReturnObject,
                    saleReturnItemName=egg_object,
                    saleReturnItemQuantity=quantity,
                    saleReturnItemUnitPrice=price,
                    saleReturnItemTotalAmount=str(total_amount),
                    saleReturnItemDiscount=discount,
                    saleReturnItemDiscountPrice=str(discounted_amount)
                )
                saleReturnItemObject.save()

                Egg.objects.filter(id=egg_object.id).update(
                    eggStockQuantity=F('eggStockQuantity') + int(quantity)
                )

                totalSaleAmountSaleReturn += total_amount
                saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn += discounted_amount
                saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn += discount

            saleReturnObject.totalSaleAmountSaleReturn = totalSaleAmountSaleReturn
            saleReturnObject.saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn = saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn
            saleReturnObject.saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn = saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn
            saleReturnObject.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Record Saved Successfully.')
            return redirect('saleReturn')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f'Some Error Occurred While Saving Data: {str(e)}')

    saleReturnData = SaleReturn.objects.all()
    results = SaleInvoice.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'pages/addSaleReturn.html', {'saleReturnData': saleReturnData, 'results': results})
```

it is retrieving id's correctly and appending it in the hidden field, and somtimes id's may be 4,5 and sometimes more than this..
Apologies for lengthy question but i hope somebody help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.